# Как сделать знак слэш неразрывным?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Можно ли как-то слэш в единицах измерения сделать неразрывным?
Пример, 0,05 мг/л.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! судя по выдаче гугла, обычно сталкиваются с [обратной проблемой](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7833149/4827341). ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обернуть единицы измерения в `span` и задать неразрывность с помощью `white-space: nowrap`:

```css
.slash {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
Можно ли как-то слэш в единицах измерения сделать неразрывным? Пример, 0,05 <span class="slash">мг/л</span>.
```

Answer (score 0):

оберни слэш знаком "word joiner" - http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2060.html

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].